# Getting "Error occured submitting the Answer" message

Tags: bug

Trying to answer: 
[Could an ARM (ARM7TDMI) Branch instruction take 6 cycles?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109295/could-arm-thumb-branch-instruction-take-6-cycles)

Getting that error message

UPDATE:
Just managed to post after getting an "Are You Human" captcha check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the text of the answer and refreshing the page?

Comment: Most certainly, four or five times.  Also tried deleting all the markup, links, etc.  Problem, as mentioned above, eventually resolved after a captcha check.  With the other post describing the same thing, maybe we were under attack or something.